# Formatting registry values with non-standard argument syntax for context menu commands

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry

I'm trying to add an entry to the Windows folder background context menu.
The following "command" value works:

```
"P:\Projects\GuardianBlade\OfStrangerFlames\Development\Project\Bin\MakeManifest.exe"
```

It successfully executes MakeManifest (a tiny development tool I'm working on for my real programming project).

However, I'd like to do this:

```
"P:\Projects\GuardianBlade\OfStrangerFlames\Development\Project\Bin\MakeManifest.exe" -root="%1"
```

But that doesn't work.
Neither does this:

```
"P:\Projects\GuardianBlade\OfStrangerFlames\Development\Project\Bin\MakeManifest.exe" "-root=%1"
```

What I'm aiming for, is the program MakeManifest.exe to execute, and receive **one** command-line argument of the format:

```
-root="the/directory/right-clicked/in/"
```

I want the quotes around the directory path to be passed into MakeManifest preserved, and I'd like the entire thing (*-root="the/directory/right-clicked/in/"*) to be one argument.

Failing that, I'd settle for *-root* passed in as one argument, and *the/directory/path* (without quotes but as one argument) passed in as the second argument. I can't get either to work.

All my attempts result in this error message:
[image]

"*This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.*"

...as if it were trying to identify what program to execute the entire command as a filepath.

Again, setting the command without any arguments works fine.

How should I do that ?

Comment: This question would be better suited for [so].

Comment: I was thinking that myself, but I wasn't sure. It's not directly programming related - it has to do with the format of shell commands on Windows.

Comment: I think it's perfectly on-topic for SU, but a possible duplicate of [What is the list of special variables available when writing a shell command for a context menu](http://superuser.com/questions/136838/what-is-the-list-of-special-variables-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for)

Comment: Yea, I found that answer after kinokijuf posted! I don't think the **question** is a duplicate, rather I think the **answer** to this question is the other topic. =P I'll add the link into kino's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%V` instead of `%1`.

For additional information on shell command variables like %V and %1, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/136838/what-is-the-list-of-special-variables-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for/473602#473602).

Comment: So would %V or %W be the proper usage? It seems like %V just imitates %W in certain circumstances. So should I always just use %W then, if I want the directory?

Comment: Hmm, [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/181668/199893) (in the linked thread) seems to imply %W actually behaves somewhat different than documented - at least in the observed results. But the poster didn't specify whether he right-clicked from within the folder, or merely on the folder icon, which might explain the deviation.