# Start MSYS in current folder

Tags: windows, mingw, msys

I have MinGW/MSYS on Windows, and can't figure how to start MSYS shell in folder I'm working in.

For example, in Windows console I'm working in folder `c:\temp` and if I call MSYS (`msys.bat`) it opens new console window in some fixed location, representing my home folder.

How to change this `msys.bat` file, so that MSYS shell opens in current working folder (or changes to it, after start)?

Comment: Can you include the contents of that batch file in your question?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/msys.bat

Comment: Unless I missed something I don't see a path being set anywhere in that batch file. My guess is that rxvt/bash are starting up in their default dirs as per their config files. You *might* be able to pass your current dir (`%cd%`) to them somehow, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm looking for: when calling bash instruct it to change in current working folder under Windows. Cygwin has similar option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of msysgit you are using, but for me calling `msys.bat` does not change the current directory. If you see the directory being changed, check the `etc/profile` file in the msysgit directory for `cd` commands. As this file gets executed when a login shell is started it might be the cause for you to always land in your home directory.

Comment: Yes, the last line in that file (...\mingw\msys\1.0\etc\profile on my system) is `cd "$HOME"`. If you comment that out bash will start in the current folder, then it's easy enough to type `cd` to go to the home folder.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, msys.bat will issue a `cd "$HOME"` from `etc/profile`. Setting the HOME environment variable to `.` gives me a mingw shell with the correct working directory.

```
set HOME=.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bash file and pass arguments to the msys2_shell.cmd to start anywhere you want it to be.

`msys2_shell.cmd -where "home/name/esp"`

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you were asking for but has the same effect.

What you could do is adding a **MSYS2 here** context menu entry. To do so add the following to your registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Conext menu entry right clicking on directories
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\msys_shell]
@="MSYS2 Here"
"Icon"="C:\\msys64\\msys2.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\msys_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\msys64\\msys2_shell.cmd\" \"-where\" \"%V\""


; Conext menu entry right clicking when in the library folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\LibraryFolder\background\shell\msys_shell]
@="MSYS2 Here"
"Icon"="C:\\msys64\\msys2.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\LibraryFolder\background\shell\msys_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\msys64\\msys2_shell.cmd\" \"-where\" \"%V.\""


; Conext menu entry right clicking not on directories but the background
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\msys_shell]
@="MSYS2 Here"
"Icon"="C:\\msys64\\msys2.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\msys_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\msys64\\msys2_shell.cmd\" \"-where\" \"%V\""


; Conext menu entry right clicking on directories
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\msys_shell]
@="MSYS2 Here"
"Icon"="C:\\msys64\\msys2.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\msys_shell\command]
@="\"C:\\msys64\\msys2_shell.cmd\" \"-where\" \"%V\""
```

- Make sure you adapt the MSYS2 installation paths accordingly
- You can find more information regarding the use of `%V` [here](https://superuser.com/a/473602/591879)
- Adding `"-use-full-path"` to lines where `msys2_shell.cmd` is called allows you to use everything in `PATH` in MSYS2

Comment: That's definitely related and looks promising. Seems that the `-where` parameter in `msys2_shell.cmd` is the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it in the folder you are working in, and you are working in that folder regularly, you can add a line to the end of `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

`cd /c/temp`

This command will be ran each time you log into the terminal.  You can get elaborate and source a file if you have multiple commands you want to run, e.g.

`. ~/etc/start_script
. ~/etc/start_script2`

This is especially useful if you already have your .bashrc configured and or don't really want to use an alternate HOME path.

Answer (score 0):

In case the modifying of `etc/profile` (commenting out of `cd "$HOME"` like in first answer) is undesirable for some reason, this could do the job:

```bsh
# in mingw:
%SystemDrive%\mingw\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c "cd '%TEMP%'; $SHELL"
# msys in root:
%SystemDrive%\msys\bin\sh.exe --login -i -c "cd '%TEMP%'; $SHELL"
```

This example would start msys shell in `/tmp` directory.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this inspiring answer](https://superuser.com/a/1633658/391675) and asking the launcher for help,

```
$> c:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -help
Usage:
    msys2_shell.cmd [options] [login shell parameters]

Options:
    -mingw32 | -mingw64 | -ucrt64 | -clang64 | -msys[2]   Set shell type
    -defterm | -mintty | -conemu                            Set terminal type
    -here                            Use current directory as working
                                     directory
    -where DIRECTORY                 Use specified DIRECTORY as working
                                     directory
    -[use-]full-path                 Use full current PATH variable
                                     instead of trimming to minimal
    -no-start                        Do not use "start" command and
                                     return login shell resulting
                                     errorcode as this batch file
                                     resulting errorcode
    -shell SHELL                     Set login shell
    -help | --help | -? | /?         Display this help and exit

Any parameter that cannot be treated as valid option and all
following parameters are passed as login shell command parameters.
```

I solved this issue like this for an up-to-date MSYS2 installation on Windows10/11 (in 2024):

Create a file `msys.cmd` in my `tools` folder (this folder is in `%PATH%`) with following contents.

```
set MSYSTEM=UCRT64
c:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -here %*
```

This will default to the nowadays encouraged `UCRT64` but will as well pass arguments like `-mingw64` (which are higher priority) to the launcher, so not much to remember.