# What does `/n "%1" /o "%u"` mean?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I ran the `ftype` command in `CMD`, and got the following output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"
```

I've seen `%1` before as the place holder for the file name but I've never seen the `/n "%1" /o "%u"` in the output of an `ftype` command before and am not sure what it means.

Comment: What was the full command that you ran?

Comment: simply run `ftype` and dig into its outputs, or limit the results by `ftype | findstr Word`

Answer (score 1):

*A preliminary answer without being entirely sure of the full command you ran:*

The command-line arguments supplied to CMD when opening a program can be elusive, at best. They're not actually arguments of the `ftype` command you ran, but a mixture of arguments from different high-level commands that Windows uses to run commands and programs from places like the Windows Registry. You're seeing them because the `ftype` command you ran returns the full path name, at the end of which the arguments being called to open the program happen to be included.

*Some* of these arguments are documented, as part of the [`cmd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) and the [`start` command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php) (see the File Associations section for the RVD link).

Others are also documented, but [much harder to come by](https://superuser.com/a/473602/323079). The linked answer is the only list of command-line arguments for opening a program that I've been able to locate among all the StackExchange sites, and the information in it comes from a now-deleted comment on an obscure source from the Microsoft Developer Network site (!).

Yet others aren't native Windows arguments, but are created and defined by the program that runs them. For example, according to [this on Microsoft Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/210565/how-to-use-startup-command-line-switches-to-start-word-2010,-word-2007,-word-2003,-word-2002,-and-word-2000), Word has its own command-line arguments, one of which appears first in your list above. According to that link, the `/n` argument is used by Word to initiate a new instance:

> /n
>
> Starts a new instance of Word with no document open. Documents opened
>   in each instance of Word will not appear as choices in the **Window** menu
>   of other instances.

You correctly guessed that the `%1` parameter refers to the filename being passed to the program, but everything that's left is likely a global command-line argument that Windows (idiotically) decided should remain undocumented.

Finding out what those are is probably something that can only be done by you, and would involving using `echo` to determine the contents of those arguments.

---

#### References

[CMD.exe - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

[Rob van der Woude - Batch files - The START command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php)

[Which special variables are available when writing a shell command for a context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/136838/which-special-variables-are-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for-a-context/473602#473602)

[How to use startup command-line switches to start Word 2010, Word 2007, Word 2003, Word 2002, and Word 2000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/210565/how-to-use-startup-command-line-switches-to-start-word-2010--word-2007)

Comment: the original command was already posted in the title

Comment: No it wasn't, your current edit to the question is grossly wrong. This is CMD. The OP's original post clearly mentioned that she ran the `ftype` command; however, she didn't include the full command she ran so we don't know what options she ran `ftype` with, hence the disclaimer in my the answer. What you're calling the "command" is not the command at all. Either you don't understand the Windows command line or you didn't read the question properly before making such drastic changes to it.

Comment: by `command` I mean the command associated to opening the file type. Where did I say that that's the command the OP was running? It should be like this `ftype Word.Document.8
Word.Document.8="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /n "%1" /o "%u"`