# NirCmd: Copy Path vs. Copy File Name

Tags: command-line, batch, nircmd

`nircmd.exe execmd (echo.|set /p=\"%1\") | clip`

Copies %1 path to the clipboard.

How can I copy the *file name* to the clipboard *using NirCmd*?

`echo. | set /p = "%~nx1" | clip` works in a BAT file.

but `nircmd.exe execmd (echo.|set /p=\"%~nx1\") | clip` does not work.

Comment: The syntax of the execmd is only for folders. .... Executes a command of Command-Prompt (Console Window) without displaying anything on the screen. 
Examples: 
execmd del "~$folder.desktop$\calc.lnk" 
execmd mkdir f:\temp\desktop1 
execmd copy "~$folder.desktop$\*.lnk" f:\temp\desktop    ... It may be a restriction of execmd. Try always putting the file name in its folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**// Edit**

> *`echo. | set /p = "%~nx1" | clip` works in a BAT file.*
> Yes, the command-line interpreter will expand the argument `%1` into the desired form, `%~nx1` (Name.Extension) of your argument passed to your bat executed by cmd.exe
>
> *but `nircmd.exe execmd (echo.|set /p="%~nx1") | clip` does not work.*
> Note that it won't work, because you want to expand a registry argument to a nircmd command complement, and that's outside of a bat that didn't take any arguments, what was passed to the registry, not a bat, by command interpreter...

There is no expansion (**`%~?!1`**) for any registry arguments:


```bat
Arguments:

%1, %D, %H, %I, %L, %S, %V, %W

Not Work/Expand:

%~nx1, %~nxD, %~nxH, %~nxI, %~nxL, %~nxS, %~nxV, %~nxW

 
Often we find "%1" in the commands associated with file types

(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FileType\shell\open\command).

In Windows 9x through 2000 (and possibly XP) this would evaluate

to the short notation of the fully qualified path of the file of type FileType.

To get the long file name, use "%L" instead of "%1".
```

---

> *How can I copy the file name to the clipboard using NirCmd?*
> It's <strike>**not**</strike> possible

- **1.** Considering that `%L` returns me the full path (with Name.eXtension)
- **2.** Considering that `%W` returns me the path only (without `%~nx`-Name.eXtention)
- **3.** Use a variable to replace and get the substring that removes the path `%W\` from the variable defined to `%L`:

```bat
C:\\Windows\\nircmd.exe execmd set "_=%L" & cmd /v /s /c "echo\|set/p;.="!_:%W\"=!"|clip"
```

- To add entries without using the command line, you can use a hybrid bat file with reg.
- Just save the file below as .cmd or .bat and run as administrator.

```bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;@(cls&%__APPDIR__%reg.exe import "%~f0" & goto :EOF)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyFileName]
@="CopyFileName"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyFileName\command]
@="C:\\\\Windows\\\\nircmd.exe execmd set \"_=%L\" & cmd /v /s /c \"echo\\|set/p;.=\"!_:%W\\=!\"|clip\""
```

**Edit //**

---

What you get using `%1` is the full path of the file, because `%1` is also an argument to the registry...

- You can try these commands and see the result, but for registry entries run as admin

```bat
%__AppDir__%reg.exe add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyFileName" /ve /d "CopyFileName" /f
%__AppDir__%reg.exe add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyFileName\command" /ve /d "C:\\Windows\\nircmd.exe execmd echo\|set/p;.=\"%1\"|clip" /t reg_sz /f
```

- **Obs.: 1** You can replace `%1` and check the results for `%D`, `%H`, `%I`, `%L`, `%S`, `%V` and `%W`.
- **Obs.: 2** You can replace `/t reg_sz` with `/t reg_expand_sz`, get the same results.
- **Obs.: 3** Using `%L` you get the the *Long fully qualified path of file*.
- **Obs.: 4** Replace my path to Nircmd.exe (`C:\\Windows\\nircmd.exe`) to your path.

---

- Consider consulting the answers to this question:
  [Which special variables are available when writing a shell command for a context](https://superuser.com/questions/136838/which-special-variables-are-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for-a-context)

---

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and very helpful reply. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest executing the command with `cmd /c` like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Nirsoft Package\NirSoft\x64\nircmd.exe" cmd /c (echo.|set /p=\"%1\") | clip
```

Note that if the purpose is to execute a `.bat` file quietly,
you may find some alternatives in the post
[Run a batch file in a completely hidden way](https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way).

Comment: It won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Why won't it work?

Comment: Is it working for you? - Anyway, I want to run `(echo.|set /p=\"%~nx1\") | clip`.

Comment: It's working for me, although with a simple string instead of `\"%1\"`, and it then does what you want. If you're encountering an error, please let me know which one.

Comment: I'm using it in a registry command. `nircmd.exe cmd /c  (echo.|set /p= "%~nx1") | clip`, I get a NirCmd error. Where are you using it? Could you please post the entire line? Thanks.

Comment: The command is in my answer. Have you given the full nircmd path, or is the folder in the PATH?

Comment: The folder is in the PATH.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/x8Z0tNNL/test.png. --- `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyFileName]
@="Copy File Name"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\CopyFileName\command]
@="nircmd.exe cmd /c (echo.|set /p= "%~nx1") | clip"`

Comment: You have not escaped the inner quotes: `\"`.